# Would an RTG used for electricity generation in space still work when being hit by sunlight?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology

An RTG (radioisotope thermoelectric generator) in a vacuum can only generate power by emitting heat via radiation. Does being hit by sunlight decrease its own heat and thus power output?

Answer (score 2):

A radioisotope thermoelectric generator is based on the thermoelectric field which produces a voltage when a temperature difference is applied to two junctions of two materials. The radioactive material heats one junction while the other remains cold. The voltage is proportional to the temperature difference. If the sun heats the cold junction, it reduces the temperature difference and thus reduces the power of the generator.

Comment: That's *if* the sun heats the cold junction. However, just because a satellite is being reached by sunlight it doesn't mean that the cold junction is directly exposed.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty - You are right. That's why I put the "if" in. By the way, the satellite will always "be reached by sunlight", it just depends on which side of the satellite and if this would heat the cold junction as compared to the hot one.

Comment: Yeah, I was mostly remarking on the silliness of the OP's premise and the thought that the cold junction is externally visible. If this is really that important for the satellite, it will have a heat radiator on the shaded side - or indeed multiple heat radiators, with the cold junction connected to whichever one is coldest. In any case, the design space is so large that it's entirely pointless to speculate.